# Save startup-configuration from switchs/routers cisco with python script?

Tags: python, cisco, netmiko

I Would like to  backup my switchs/routers configuration cisco automatically.

I try to create this script :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
#-*- conding: utf-8 -*-

from netmiko import ConnectHandler

cisco_test = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'host': 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    'username': 'xxxxxx',
    'password': 'xxxxxxxxxx',
    'secret': 'xxxxxxx',
    }

net_connect = ConnectHandler(**cisco_test)
net_connect.enable()

config_commands = ['copy start tftp://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/test.bin']

output = net_connect.send_config_set(config_commands)

print(output)
net_connect.exit_enable_mode()
```

But it doesn't work... Could you show me how to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You were sending them as "config commands". In IOS, copying to a TFTP server must be done from Privileged EXEC mode. If executed from Global Config, the command will not work unless it is preceded by "do" as in `do copy start tftp://...`.

Are you trying to back up the startup config to a TFTP server? Interesting choice to name the config "test.bin" btw.

You can do this in 2 ways:

1. Backup over TFTP to a device, like you are doing
2. Backup to a file by capturing the output of a "show run" command

Cool thing about the second option: even if you're device is having problems reaching a TFTP server, you can still back up the config.

**METHOD 1**

You will need to not only send the copy command, but you'll need to respond to the prompts you'll receive:

```
CISCO2921-K9#copy start tftp://10.122.151.118/cisco2921-k9-backup
Address or name of remote host [10.122.151.118]? 
Destination filename [cisco2921-k9-backup]? 
!!
1759 bytes copied in 0.064 secs (27484 bytes/sec)

CISCO2921-K9#
```

So you must be prepared to respond with "Enter" for both questions

This is an example for what a working script will look like:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler

# enter the IP for your TFTP server here
TFTP_SERVER = "10.1.1.1"

# to add a device, define its connection details below, then add its name 
# to the list of "my_devices"
device1 = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'host': '10.1.1.1',
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': 'cisco123',
    'secret': 'cisco123',
}

device2 = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_xr',
    'host': '10.1.1.2',
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': 'cisco123',
    'secret': 'cisco123',
}

# make sure you add every device above to this list
my_devices = [device1, device2]

# This is where the action happens. Connect, backup, respond to prompts
# Feel free to change the date on the backup file name below, 
# everything else should stay the same
i = 0
for device in my_devices:
    i += 1
    name = f"device{str(i)}"
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**device)
    net_connect.enable()
    copy_command = f"copy start tftp://{TFTP_SERVER}/{name}-backup-02-26-2020"

    output = net_connect.send_command_timing(copy_command)
    if "Address or name" in output:
        output += net_connect.send_command_timing("\n")
    if "Destination filename" in output:
        output += net_connect.send_command_timing("\n")
    net_connect.disconnect
    print(output)
```

I hope this was helpful. Let me know if you have any more questions